# Close all files in a folder

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have the following code that opens all files in a specified folder

```
Sub OpenFiles()
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    MyFolder = "\\ILAFILESERVER\Public\Documents\Renewable Energy\FiTs\1 Planning Department\Marks Tracker\Quality Control Reports"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Is it possible to have a similar code that closes all files in the folder. Many thanks in advance for any assistance provided on this matter.

Answer (score 3):

Workbooks.Open will return a reference to the pointer of the workbook. Save this in a Collection (using Collection.Add) as soon as you open the workbook. When you want to close all  the workbooks, iterate through the collection (using For Each) and close each element. Then remove all elements from the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`Workbooks.Close`

From the Excel Visual Basic Help documentation:

> This example closes all open workbooks. If there are changes in any open workbook, Microsoft Excel displays the appropriate prompts and dialog boxes for saving changes.

Comment: Be careful though because this will close the workbook containing the running VBA code as well, which might not be your intention.

Comment: @JoelSpolsky Thanks for the caveat, it's one more option for the OP to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have them all open at the same time? Because otherwise:

```
Sub OpenFiles()
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    MyFolder = "\\ILAFILESERVER\Public\Documents\Renewable Energy\FiTs\1 Planning Department\Marks Tracker\Quality Control Reports"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
        'Do stuff
        wb.Close False 'The false will close without saving
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Dan - Yes, they all have to be open at the same time, and then I would look to close them all at the same time

Comment: ALso you can loopthrough the open workbooks like this: For Each wbk In Workbooks and I'm sure you can then go wbk.Close